# How to configure WorkItem in AzureDevops for Incremented Iteration ID

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem, azure-boards

I have a requirement as Below:

1. Create a new Work Item in Azure Devops
2. It should have the IterationID as **1**
3. If I modify something in that WorkItem say "**Description**" it should increment the Iteration ID.

In my case, If I create a new Work Item Say "**User Story**", Its getting Created with the Iteration ID **"2"**

Though I change the Description its remains the Same.

Below Are the Detail Steps That I have followed.

- Created the User story as a WorkItem 
  [image]
- Its Get Created with Iteration ID 2
  [image]
- Modified The user story (Change the Description)

[image]

- Still The Iteration ID Remains Unchanged

[image]

- Below is the history page Of that user story.

[image]

Please let me know what configuration do I need to implement to meet the Requirements.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you want to increment Iteration ID in each save?

Answer (score 1):

Work items are already versioned. You do not need to add a custom field for this purpose.

Look at the revision ID field. I believe it's called `rev`.

Additionally, "iteration" **already has a meaning**, so you should avoid adding an additional field that redefines the term, otherwise you are going to have terminology confusion in the future.